# Deploying an angular 6 app using fabric.js on heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, angular6, fabricjs

I have to deploy an angular 6 application that uses fabric.js on heroku. I have done all the steps required for deploying a simple angular 6 app and the simple app worked. But, with fabricjs, it does not.

Here is the package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "projname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.8.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fabric": "^2.4.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/fabric": "^1.5.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "surge": "^0.20.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

All the required dependencies for a simple angular 6 app have been done. The server has also been set up. Here is the server.js file.

```js
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/projname'));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/projname/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

And, lastly here is the output. I think there is some problem with the node_module canvas. Thanks.

```js
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.9.4
       engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.0
       
       Resolving node version 8.9.4...
       Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
       npm 5.6.0 already installed with node
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       
       > canvas@1.6.12 install /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/canvas
       > node-gyp rebuild
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/canvas/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
         COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:20:0:
       ../src/JPEGStream.h: In function ‘boolean empty_closure_output_buffer(j_compress_ptr)’:
       ../src/JPEGStream.h:42:108: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)dest->closure->fn, 2, argv);
                                                                                                                   ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:20:0:
       ../src/JPEGStream.h: In function ‘void term_closure_destination(j_compress_ptr)’:
       ../src/JPEGStream.h:63:113: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)dest->closure->fn, 2, data_argv);
                                                                                                                        ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:20:0:
       ../src/JPEGStream.h:71:112: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)dest->closure->fn, 2, end_argv);
                                                                                                                       ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static void Canvas::ToBufferAsyncAfter(uv_work_t*)’:
       ../src/Canvas.cc:221:31: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            closure->pfn->Call(1, argv);
                                      ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:1655:3: note: declared here
          Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
          ^~~~
       ../src/Canvas.cc:226:31: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            closure->pfn->Call(2, argv);
                                      ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:1655:3: note: declared here
          Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
          ^~~~
       ../src/Canvas.cc: In function ‘cairo_status_t streamPNG(void*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int)’:
       ../src/Canvas.cc:377:102: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)closure->fn, 3, argv);
                                                                                                             ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Canvas::StreamPNGSync(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
       ../src/Canvas.cc:446:103: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)closure.fn, 1, argv);
                                                                                                              ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/Canvas.cc:452:103: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)closure.fn, 1, argv);
                                                                                                              ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       ../src/Canvas.cc: In function ‘cairo_status_t streamPDF(void*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int)’:
       ../src/Canvas.cc:476:77: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), closure->fn, 3, argv);
                                                                                    ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:958:46: note: declared here
          NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:8:0:
       ../src/PNG.h: In function ‘cairo_status_t canvas_write_png(cairo_surface_t*, png_rw_ptr, void*)’:
       ../src/PNG.h:73:20: warning: variable ‘status’ might be clobbered by ‘longjmp’ or ‘vfork’ [-Wclobbered]
            cairo_status_t status = CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
                           ^~~~~~
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/color.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Image.o
       ../src/Image.cc: In member function ‘void Image::loaded()’:
       ../src/Image.cc:380:25: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            onload->Call(0, NULL);
                                ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Image.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:1655:3: note: declared here
          Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
          ^~~~
       ../src/Image.cc: In member function ‘void Image::error(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
       ../src/Image.cc:393:26: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            onerror->Call(1, argv);
                                 ^
       In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
                        from ../src/Image.cc:7:
       ../../nan/nan.h:1655:3: note: declared here
          Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
          ^~~~
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/ImageData.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/init.o
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/FontFace.o
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas.node
         COPY Release/canvas.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/canvas/build'
       
       > node-sass@4.9.3 install /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/install.js
       
       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/linux-x64-57_binding.node
       Download complete
       Binary saved to /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.Ba6aC/node-sass/4.9.3/linux-x64-57_binding.node
       
       > circular-json@0.5.7 postinstall /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/circular-json
       > echo ''; echo "\x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor."; echo ''
       
       
       \x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor.
       
       
       > node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/build.js
       
       Binary found at /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
       Testing binary
       Binary is fine
       
       > bimscoper@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_2bdbd84339a09d50e7de179986c6e0f3
       > ng build -prod
       
       Unknown option: '-p'
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! bimscoper@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build -prod`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the bimscoper@0.0.0 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Ba6aC/_logs/2018-10-18T18_42_10_164Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey do you resolved your issue ?

Did you  simply try add the [link cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.5/fabric.min.js%22) or fabric project `<script src="./assets/fabric.js"></script>` in asset to your index on the angular project ?

after imports, declare fabric as any

```
declare const fabric: any;
```

Use it in AfterViewInit in your component and move fabric initialization into ngAfterViewInit event handler

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
       const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
       const rect = new fabric.Rect({
          top : 100,
          left : 100,
          width : 60,
          height : 70,
          fill : 'red'
       });
       canvas.add(rect);
}
```